# Socket.io namespace with variable/id in route

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem:

I use a **room join system** [which I programmed only in NodeJS] and **socket.io**.

https://example.com/room/:roomid/

e.g. https://example.com/room/764363553/

my route:

```
router.get('/room/:roomid/', function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.roomid;
    //....
});
```

**I want to make sockets in rooms, but how I make it with the namespace?**

```
io.of("/room/:roomid/").on('connection', function (socket) {
   io.of("/room/:roomid/").emit('testsocket');
}
```

**-> does not work**

client code:

```
var socketIO = io(window.location.pathname);

socketIO.on('testsocket', function (data) {
        console.log("socket successful connected!");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work` ? Does it throw an error ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev I mean: the socket does not connect.

Comment: Can you then also add the code you use to connect.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Yes, but if I emit something it does not arrive.

Comment: Please, add the code here. I cannot debug things that I can't see. Meanwhile you're telling me contradicting points.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Ok I added the code, thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server

```
var manager = io.of("/room").on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on("join", function(roomid){
       socket.join(roomid);
       manager.to(roomid).emit('testsocket',roomid);
   }
}
```

Client:

```
var socketIO = io("/room");
var roomID = window.location.pathname.splitOnLast("/")[1]; //Should ideally be got from req.params.roomid
socketIO.emit("join", roomID)
socketIO.on('testsocket', function (data) {
    console.log("Connected to room", data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Socketio supports Dynamic namespace since 2.1.0.

The pr is [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/pull/3195).

[document is here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#serverofnsp):

A regex or a function can also be provided, in order to create namespace in a dynamic way:

```
const dynamicNsp = io.of(/^\/dynamic-\d+$/).on('connect', (socket) => {
  const newNamespace = socket.nsp; // newNamespace.name === '/dynamic-101'

  // broadcast to all clients in the given sub-namespace
  newNamespace.emit('hello');
});

// client-side
const socket = io('/dynamic-101');

// broadcast to all clients in each sub-namespace
dynamicNsp.emit('hello');

// use a middleware for each sub-namespace
dynamicNsp.use((socket, next) => { /* ... */ });
```

With a function:

```
io.of((name, query, next) => {
  next(null, checkToken(query.token));
}).on('connect', (socket) => { /* ... */ });
```